# Authenticated principal is lost after Zuul redirect to a microservice registered in Eureka

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have this set-up in order to work with the Netflix stack:

- An Eureka Server
- A module, exposed to the outside world with a Zuul proxy (registered to Eureka)
- A number of back-end microservices (registered to Eureka)

My problem is, when I invoke an URL in the proxy (to be redirected to the microservice) for the second/third time, **the autenthicated principal is lost**.

These are the log entries:

```
09:14:31.300  INFO 8720 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 14 09:14:31 CEST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={message=Access is denied, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException}]
09:14:33.387  INFO 8720 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 14    09:14:33 CEST 2015, principal=eadmin, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: DE9DEDCB6A809133C54ABC3403A46B38}]
09:14:33.387  INFO 8720 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 14 09:14:33 CEST 2015, principal=eadmin, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: DE9DEDCB6A809133C54ABC3403A46B38}]
09:14:35.407  INFO 8720 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.filters.ProxyRouteLocator   : Finding route for path: /userregistryservice/user-registry/getAllRoles
09:23:40.119  INFO 8720 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.c.n.zuul.filters.ProxyRouteLocator   : Finding route for path: /userregistryservice/user-registry/getAllRoles
09:24:06.689  INFO 8720 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 14 09:24:06 CEST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={message=Access is denied, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException}]
```

I have implemented a Zuul proxy, where I pass the principal to the request headers to be redirected but when the request is sent for the second time, this filter is not invoked (**Spring Security captures the request as it were an anonymous request**).

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Investigating with Fiddler, I have found out that the request being reject is answered with a HTTP 302 code, after two successful requests:

[image: Fidller request log]

**EDIT #2**: This is my Spring´s boot security configuration

```
@Autowired
private RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteminderFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 // @formatter:off
    http.anonymous().and().addFilter(siteminderFilter)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/authfallback/**", "/access_requests.css")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**")
        .fullyAuthenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**/metrics")
        .hasAnyRole("SYSTEM", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/logs")
        .hasAnyRole("SYSTEM", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user-registry/**")
        .hasAnyRole("SYSTEM", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/AdminTools/**", "/api-docs")
        .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/sdoc.jsp", "o2c.html")
        .denyAll()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .hasAnyRole("SYSTEM", "ENGINEERING", "CUSTOMER", "EXECUTIVE", "ADMIN").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/authfallback/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html", false)
        .permitAll().and().logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(wamLogoutHandler).and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/auth/authorizationrequest").and().csrf().disable();
 // @formatter:on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to zuul:

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders:
```